# tar: streaming file size

Tags: tar

I'm trying to know in advance the approximate size of a tar file while it's being streamed to stdout. According to the spec (http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/Standard.html), the first 500 bytes are the header (ASCII-formatted), and bytes 124 to 136 specify the file size.

But, because it's streaming, those bytes always display 00000000 since I suppose filesize is calculated on-the-fly, or at the end.

```
tar -cf - myfolder | dd count=12 skip=124 iflag=count_bytes,skip_bytes > filesize
```

Always results in:

```
00000000000^@
```

I'm not using compression, so the tarball is roughly the size of the original data. Can tar somehow provide this information in the header before completion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, it cannot be calculated in advance while streaming.